# Grunt: Fatal error: watch EPERM

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

You can view/clone the full code here: https://github.com/mlewisTW/grunt-tests

I'd like to *watch* the `src` directory (to minify, concat, less, etc), which puts everything into the `build` dir.  I'd also like to *watch* the `build` dir in order to livereload.  Here's the watch config snippet:

```
watch: {
        options: {
            livereload: false
        },
        build: {
            files: ['<%= srcDir %>/**/*'],
            tasks: 'build'
        },
        reload: {
            files: ['<%= buildDir %>/**/*'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        }
    },
```

I'm on Windows 8.  I'm getting a `Fatal error: watch EPERM` when I change a file, and it starts the first step of the `build` task (clean).  I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to delete a watched directory.

Is there a way to turn off the livereload watch task when I build, and then restart it when its finished?

Is there another/better way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/issues/163 -> it seems a "random" Windows issue, according to this issue after first time, a second "grunt watch" solves the issue. Can you try it? Otherwise it could be something permission related, is your shell/git shell/ sth running in administration mode ?

Comment: El Capitan is also experiencing this, some have said due to the rootless change where /usr/bin is no longer writeable. Are you on El Capitan?

Comment: Permissions of Node & NPM can be a bit messy when installed manually or via a package manager. I suggest trying it by installing [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) which goes under your personal directory and has no permission collisions. The repo above works fine in my env and I'm using node `v6.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

From [Github issues:](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/issues/163)

> EPERM on Windows means that you can delete or write to a file.
>
> It is usually because another process is holding a handle to the file.
>
> Sometimes, this happens a bit randomly with nodeJS on Windows. I find it 
>     is fine if you run it a second time.

Comment: As pointed out by @Dave Foster, in the future you should probably cite the source of an answer if you copy it verbatim.